# GQL get ID field

Tags: python, google-app-engine

On google appengine, you can retrieve the hash key value by doing a query like

```
select __key__ from furniture
```

But appengine datastore maintains a nicely autoincremented field ID for each kind.

How can I access it from a query?

```
select ID from furniture
```

Doesn't work

Comment: The ID isn't "autoincremented".  They're guaranteed to be unique across a single kind & entity group, but they're unlikely to be continuous and not guaranteed to be increasing.  (On the development server they are sequential.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that a Gcl query cannot incorporate calls to accessor methods or attribute extraction (much in the same vein as the fact it can only do `"SELECT * FROM"` to fetch whole entities or `"SELECT __key__ FROM"` to fetch keys only -- it cannot pick and choose fields as in [hypothetical!-)] `"SELECT this, that FROM`").

So, you need to fetch the keys, then call each key's `.id()` accessor (if you want `None` for keys that don't have an ID but rather a name; use `.id_or_name()` if you'd rather get the name, if available, and `None` only as a last resort).  E.g., to get non-None IDs only:

```
thekeys = db.GqlQuery('SELECT __key__ FROM Whatever').fetch(1000)
theids = [k.id() for k in thekeys if k.id() is not None]
```

Comment: Absolutely correct, except that the condition should probably be "if k.has_id()" - or omit it and use "k.id_or_name()".

Comment: @Nick, thanks! `has_id` is NOT documented at http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keyclass.html so I'm reluctant to use it or advise others to use it -- if that's a docs bug, I'll be glad to open it in the tracker and/or help fit it in 20% time, of course;-).

Answer (score 5):

you could also try

```
entity.key().id()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it was there back then when you have asked this question, but now it is pretty easy to retrieve entity by id.

```
YourModel.get_by_id (int(ids))
```

You can read more about it here in the documentation: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass#Model_get_by_id